# What are the basic criteria for adding predictors in a binary logistic regression model

Tags: logistic, feature-selection, binary-data

I am trying to run logistic regression. What are the basic criteria for adding predictors in a binary logistic regression model?

Comment: You should avid collinearity (highly correlated predictors). Beware of over-fitting (to many predictors relative to your sample size). No more criteria come to my mind.

Comment: The predictors should be correlated with the outcome?!

Comment: @Björn actually individual correlation isn't required, check out this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344715/multiple-regression-control-variable-effects/344722#344722

Comment: Well, in the multivariate sense. If, even after taking into account other variables, a variable does not correlate with the outcome, there is no reason to include it in a model.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so we can say that we select variables by purposeful selection?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much the same as for linear regression.  Reasons to include

Is the effect large in some substantive way?

Does adding the variable affect other parameters meaningfully?

Is it "necessary"? That is, would a model without this variable be laughed at?

Is it part of your hypotheses?

Would a small effect be notable?

Is it part of an important interaction?

---

Reasons to exclude:

Overfitting

Colinearity