# Data association

Tags: bivariate

I have a typical question if someone can help.

Construct two bivariate data sets (choose number of cases to suit yourself), each with correlation above 0.9, so that the combined data set has negative correlation.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What progress have you made with this [tag:self-study] question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/366667/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/478463/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/316319/919 and more generally see our posts on [Simpson's Paradox](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=simpson+paradox+is%3Aanswer).

Comment: I am able to get two set of bivariate data with correlation greater than .9. But I don't know how to combine them to get a negative correlation

Comment: This excercise deals with a common misconception found among many beginning statisticians. If we merge two data sets each with high positive correlation, it seems reasonable to expect that the merged data will also have positive correlation. This exercise asks you to find a counter example.